# Including rules for development and production mode separately in the webpack config file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm working on a front end project using html. In my project I'm using Webpack module bundler. I'm using **image-webpack-loader** package for optimizing images. now the problem is when I run development server it **image-webpack-loader** also run on every changes, which is requiring more loading time. For this I want to use this only in production. How can I do this without the help of any other packages. This is my first project with webpack. I'll be glad If anyone help me about this. Thanks in advance.

Here is my **webpack.config.js** file

```js
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const glob = require("glob");

module.exports = {
    mode: "production",
  entry: "./src/js/app.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "js/bundle.js",
  },
  devServer: {
    static: {
      directory: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
    },
    watchFiles: ["src/**/*"],
    compress: true,
    port: 3000,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/i,
        loader: "html-loader",
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|ico|eot|ttf|woff)$/i,
        type: "asset",
        **use: [
          {
            loader: "image-webpack-loader",
            options: {
              mozjpeg: {
                progressive: true,
                quality: 65,
              },
              optipng: {
                enabled: true,
                optimizationLevel: 7,
              },
              pngquant: {
                quality: [0.6, 0.8],
              },
              gifsicle: {
                interlaced: false,
              },
              webp: {
                quality: 75,
              },
            },
          },
        ],
        parser: {
          dataUrlCondition: {
            maxSize: 10 * 1024,
          },
        },**
        generator: {
          filename: "images/[name]-[hash][ext]",
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    ...glob.sync("./src/**/*.html").map((file) => {
      return new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: file,
        filename: path.basename(file),
        chunks: ["main"],
      });
    }),
  ],
};
```

Here is the problem I'm talking about

```js
use: [
  {
    loader: "image-webpack-loader",
    options: {
      mozjpeg: {
        progressive: true,
        quality: 65,
      },
      optipng: {
        enabled: true,
        optimizationLevel: 7,
      },
      pngquant: {
        quality: [0.6, 0.8],
      },
      gifsicle: {
        interlaced: false,
      },
      webp: {
        quality: 75,
      },
    },
  },
],
parser: {
  dataUrlCondition: {
    maxSize: 10 * 1024,
  },
},
```

please edit this for production and development so that I can use it to the same file

```
{
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|ico|eot|ttf|woff)$/i,
        type: "asset",
        **use: [
          {
            loader: "image-webpack-loader",
            options: {
              mozjpeg: {
                progressive: true,
                quality: 65,
              },
              optipng: {
                enabled: true,
                optimizationLevel: 7,
              },
              pngquant: {
                quality: [0.6, 0.8],
              },
              gifsicle: {
                interlaced: false,
              },
              webp: {
                quality: 75,
              },
            },
          },
        ],
        parser: {
          dataUrlCondition: {
            maxSize: 10 * 1024,
          },
        },**
        generator: {
          filename: "images/[name]-[hash][ext]",
        },
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Option 1. **Separate webpack configuration** for each environment.

See [Production](https://webpack.js.org/guides/production/) best practices:

> We typically recommend writing **separate webpack configurations** for each environment.

> While we will separate the production and development specific bits out, note that we'll still maintain a "common" configuration to keep things DRY. In order to merge these configurations together, we'll use a utility called [webpack-merge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-merge). With the "common" configuration in place, we won't have to duplicate code within the environment-specific configurations.

So, the `image-webpack-loader` will only be used in the `webpack.prod.js` file. And `webpack.prod.js` file is used for the production build.

For local development, you don't need to include this loader in the `webpack.dev.js` file.

Option 2. Use [`disable`](https://github.com/tcoopman/image-webpack-loader#disable) option

We need to use [Environment Variables](https://webpack.js.org/guides/environment-variables/#root) in `webpack.config.js` file

`webpack.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = (env) => {
    console.log(env.imageLoaderDisable, typeof JSON.parse(env.imageLoaderDisable));

    return {
        mode: 'development',
        entry: './src/index.js',
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.(gif|png|jpe?g|svg)$/i,
                    use: [
                        'file-loader',
                        {
                            loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
                            options: {
                                disable: JSON.parse(env.imageLoaderDisable),
                            },
                        },
                    ],
                },
            ],
        },
    };
};
```

CLI:

```
$ npx webpack --env imageLoaderDisable=true
```

Comment: Many many thanks for your help. But I want to do it in webpack.config.js file without the use of  any extra package or creating one more file, Is there any way for this? Thanks in advance

Comment: @MahabubHossain Did you try the second solution?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't tried it. I told you that this is my first project with webpack.. can You please edit this for development and production,,,in development image-webpac-loader'll be disabled and for production it'll be enable  so that I can easily copy paste from you. Thanks in advance. Please check, I updated my codes